# "WinError 10061" Cannot use requests in python vs code

Tags: python, request

doing something such as

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
print(response.status_code)
```

gets me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 492, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 468, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1097, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000212D921CEF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000212D921CEF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rex\Documents\Py DeepR\Py DeepR.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000212D921CEF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

i have tried all fixes i have seen on this website, such as allowing vs code through firewall or running vs code as administrator, adding a proxy through internet options. and also setting a proxy this way

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "https://10.10.1.10:1080",
}


response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", proxies=proxies)
print(response.status_code)
```

which gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 777, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1046, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 212, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000192714C5A90>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=None)')    

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Unable to connect to proxy', ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000192714C5A90>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000192714C5A90>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=None)')))       

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Rex\Documents\Py DeepR\Py DeepR.py", line 9, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", proxies=proxies)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000192714C5A90>, 'Connection to 10.10.1.10 timed out. (connect timeout=None)')))
```

any help would be appreciated as i am very new to this

on a probably unrelated note trying to sign up to this website using google or github gave me "request lacked state, may have been forged" leaving me having to sign up normally using an email and password, this is probably useless info but i thought id mention it if its related somehow
thanks in advance

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" -- that doesn't necessarily indicate an error on your side! BTW: I can't fetch that URL from my browser either, so it has nothing to do with Python's `request` module. I guess it's simply  the wrong URL.